# Deleting the first column of csv via batch commands

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, csv

Is there a way to delete the first column of a csv using a batch command file? I have data in this first column but I want to get rid of it and output a new file starting at the 2nd column.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be cmd-line? You could easily do this in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

What about?

`cut -f 2- <file>`

EDIT: The delimiter can be defined with -d

Comment: cut isn't available on Windows by default.

Comment: +1 for using `2-` instead of `2-9` (or even `2-42`).